# How can I flag a review?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags

Someone edited my answer and changed the response. I had 3 approved and 1 rejected the edit.

I edited the answer back to original but I want to flag that user because I see all his edits are getting rejected.

He has 9 reviews all rejected except for the last one (that just happens to be mine). I'm pretty sure this user doesn't understand the purpose of review because it totally changed my answer.

The answer is : [How to force Chrome browser to reload .css file while debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562384/how-to-force-chrome-browser-to-reload-css-file-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/16403336#16403336)

I can't find flag options on the edits. So how can I flag a review?

Answer (score 4):

You can just flag the post, if you want, and explain the situation, but there really isn't much that the moderator can do other than roll back the edit, which you've already done.  There is no special flag for a review of a post; simply flag the post itself and explain that it is an edit that is the problem.

Theoretically the reviewers of the suggested edit should have rejected the edit (one did, three approved it) so it's *possible* for a moderator to see of these reviewers are consistently approving inappropriate edits.

However, unless you see a pattern of behavior, or aren't capable of rolling back the edit in question yourself, there isn't really much for a mod to do if you were to flag the post for their attention.

Of course if the inappropriate edit is re-applied, after you have already rolled it back, *then* you should flag the post for moderator attention, rather than getting into a rollback war with another user.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Ok. I wanted to flag the user because I think he needs to understand the purpose of editing and how to do it. There is a pattern, which is all his edits are getting rejected. I'll flag the post in itself as you suggested for a mod to take a look.